# Implement an interface while calling a method (inline)

Tags: c#

In Java, assuming that class A is an interface/abstract class, I can do the following:

```
callMethod(new A(){

     public void myFunc(){
     System.out.println("test");
     }
});
```

How can I achieve the same shortcut effect in C# without having to declare a class seperately  .

Thanks

Comment: In C# you cannot implement an interface with an anonymous class. But in C# there is much less reason to do so. There is no such thing as a `FunctionalInterface`. Instead we have delegates, and we use delegate objects rather than implementations of a `FunctionalInterface`. Instead, the signature of `CallMethod(Action action)` and you would pass in `() => Console.WriteLine("test")`.

Comment: Voting to reopen as this question actually looks like a question on `FunctionalInterface` in JAVA and `Delegate`s in C#.

Comment: Thank you. That looks interesting. I didn't even know this existed as I am learning c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

C# does not allow you to implement interfaces on Anonymous Types.